# get_posts() forcing ignore sticky posts on main loop

Tags: loop, get-posts

I have a custom query using `get_posts()` that besides ignoring sticky on its main query, ignores sticky posts on main loop. Reading around I've found that `get_posts()` have some trouble with sticky but couldn't found a solution to my needs.

The sticky post is shown normally but not at the top, which is unexpected.

How can I get it working properly?

args I'm using:

```
'numberposts'       => 5, 
'category_name'     => '',
'post_status'       => 'publish', 
'post_type'         => 'post',
'meta_key'          => '',
'orderby'           => '',
'order'             => ''
```

Comment: can you paste the arguments that you are passing to `get_posts()`?

Comment: @Will the Web Mechanic arguments included.

Answer (score 1):

From the function reference for `get_posts()`:

> For full parameters list see `WP_Query`.

From the `WP_Query` reference:

> ignore_sticky_posts (boolean) - ignore sticky posts or not (available with Version 3.1, replaced caller_get_posts parameter). Default value is 0 - don't ignore sticky posts. Note: ignore/exclude sticky posts being included at the beginning of posts returned, but the sticky post will still be returned in the natural order of that list of posts returned.

So, with that, if you add `ignore_sticky_posts => 0` to your array of arguments being passed to `get_posts()` your sticky posts should be output at the top as expected.

Comment: It should but it doesn't

Comment: so, yeah, I dug into the `get_posts()` function - it sets `ignore_sticky_posts` to `true` because if it's not then it causes a runaway loop and will shut down everything. Sorry, you're going to have to either adapt one of the solutions you've read about to work for you or come up with one on your own. Why not use `WP_Query`?

Comment: using WP_Query will cost me a time that I don't have restructuring all the code. Anyway thank you for your response.